# Handling strings in python

Tags: python, string, parsing

I have 2 strings:

```
s7="ONE : TWO : THREE : FOUR : FIVE 30.1 : SIX 288.3 : SEVEN 1.9 : EIGHT 45.3 :"    
s8="ONE : TWO : THREE : FOUR 155.5 : FIVE 334.7 : SIX 6.7 : SEVEN 44.5 :"
```

I'm using the following code to parse it:

```
c=s.count(':')
if c==8:
    res=""
    res=s.split(' : ')
    res = [item.strip() for item in s.split(':')]
    for index, item in enumerate(res):
        print index, item
if c==7:
    res=""
    res=s.split(' : ')
    res = [item.strip() for item in s.split(':')]
    for index, item in enumerate(res):
        print index, item
```

This output i get is

```
>>> parse(s7)
0 ONE
1 TWO
2 THREE
3 FOUR
4 FIVE 30.1
5 SIX 288.3
6 SEVEN 1.9
7 EIGHT 45.3
8 
>>> parse(s8)
0 ONE
1 TWO
2 THREE
3 FOUR 155.5
4 FIVE 334.7
5 SIX 6.7
6 SEVEN 44.5
7
```

How can I extract the numerical values from index 4 to 7 in s7 and index 3 to 6 in s8? I need to store these values so I can write them into a database later.

I've tried a couple of things but they aren't working.

Please help.

Comment: First of all I don't get why you split the conditions into 2, they do exactly the same.  
Secondly in each of the conditional parts the 1st two assignments to `res` are redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a list comprehension as well.

Assuming the strings always take on the format you provided then this would work:

```
def parse(s):
    results = [float(x) for x in s.split(' ') if x.count('.') == 1]
```

`>> [30.1, 288.3, 1.9, 45.3]`

`>> [155.5, 334.7, 6.7, 44.5]`

This code says:

```
for every `x` in the split string, which I've split on whitespace, 
cast it to a float if x's count of `.` is 1.
```

Using `count()` here works since it won't raise any exceptions if it doesn't find any occurences of the `.` however if you want to use exception handling then `index()` would be the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Does it always look like that? you can simply do:

```
s7="ONE : TWO : THREE : FOUR : FIVE 30.1 : SIX 288.3 : SEVEN 1.9 : EIGHT 45.3 :"
for elem in s7.split(' '):
    try:
        print elem
        total += float(elem)
    except:
        pass
s7 = total
>>> s7
365.6
```

And do the same for `s8` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression on each string:

```
[A-Z][ ]+([\d.]+)
```

For each string, the value you're looking for will be in the first captured group, if not empty. You can see exactly what's going on at [www.debuggex.com](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%5BA-Z%5D%5B%20%5D%2b%28%5B%5Cd.%5D%2b%29&flags=&str=0%20ONE%0A1%20TWO%0A2%20THREE%0A3%20FOUR%0A4%20FIVE%2030.1%0A5%20SIX%20288.3%0A6%20SEVEN%201.9%0A7%20EIGHT%2045.3%0A%0A0%20ONE%0A1%20TWO%0A2%20THREE%0A3%20FOUR%20155.5%0A4%20FIVE%20334.7%0A5%20SIX%206.7%0A6%20SEVEN%2044.5).

Full code:

```
import re

s7="ONE : TWO : THREE : FOUR : FIVE 30.1 : SIX 288.3 : SEVEN 1.9 : EIGHT 45.3 :"

def parse(s):
  res = s.split(' : ')
  matches = [re.search('[A-Z][ ]+([\d.]+)', x) for x in res]
  return [float(x.group(1)) for x in matches if x is not None]

print(parse(s7)) // prints "[30.1, 288.3, 1.9, 45.3]"
```